# NSString datetime to NSDate

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I'm having a hard time trying to convert a NSString to NSDate. I try lots of date format convinations, but no worked.

My string is:
5/17/2013 12:00:00 AM

And I'm using:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"M/d/y hh:mm:ss a"];
[dateFormat setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"]];
NSDate *cI = [dateFormat dateFromString:@"5/17/2013 2:00:00 AM"];
[dateFormat release];
```

I also try with:

- M/d/y h:mm:ss a
- M/d/y hh:mm:ss
- M/d/y h:mm:ss

But always cI is a nil.

Comment: When/where do you log "cI".  Are you NSLogging it immediately after the dateFromString, or somewhere else?

Comment: Once again, where are you logging "cl"???  How do you know it's nil right after the dateFromString operation??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a"];
[dateFormat setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"]];
NSDate *cI = [dateFormat dateFromString:@"5/17/2013 2:00:00 AM"];
[dateFormat release];
```

> Output: 2013-05-17 02:00:00 +0000

Comment: Anoop, I'm copy and paste your code and I get a <nil>

Comment: @Tony: as you can see in screen shot, its working!!!

Comment: setDateFormat is different in the message and in the screen. Any way I try both but no works. May be is something different in my enviroment.

Comment: yes just for showing you, even that works.... even your code is good. try clean and build again.

Comment: I create a new project copy&paste the code and I also get nil :S

Comment: *cough* don't forget to set the en_US_POSIX locale (see http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1480/_index.html )

Comment: Thank you very much Anoop, this solve my problem: 
[dateFormat setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"]];

Answer (score 0):

here, it works fine on my locale
@"MM/dd/YYYY h:mm:ss a"